# Universal property of limits of invertible sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, line-bundles, invertible-sheaves, limits-and-colimits

Let $R$ be a discrete valuation ring, $m$ the maximal ideal and $f:X \to \mathrm{Spec}(R)$ be a flat, proper morphism of relative dimension $1$. Assume further that $X$ is regular. For any $n>0$, denote by $X_n:=X \times_{\mathrm{Spec}(R)} \mathrm{Spec}(R/m^n)$ and by $i_n:X_n \hookrightarrow X$ the natural closed immersion.

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be an invertible sheaf on $X$. Suppose $\mathcal{L}'$ is another invertible sheaf on $X$ satisfying the property: for all $n>0$, $i_n^*\mathcal{L} \cong i_n^*\mathcal{L}'$. Is  $\mathcal{L} \cong \mathcal{L}'$? Any reference which deals with similar questions will be also very welcome.

Comment: Doesn't this follow from the formal function theorem? Have you looked at Hartshorne?

Comment: You'd better ask that the various isomorphisms are compatible with respect to pullback by the transition maps. Once you do that, there's a (more general) theorem of Grothendieck that gives an equivalence of categories between formal coherent sheaves and coherent sheaves on $X$.
(I remember this from http://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.0497v2.pdf, thm 6.48, but there are certainly better references, for example FGA explained chapter 8, that we give there)

Comment: @MattiaTalpo All the results that I am seeing assumes $R$ is complete under certain valuation. Is there a reference where $R$ is not necessarily complete?

Comment: @Mohan: Could you please elaborate a little more on how to use the formal function theorem.

Comment: Replacing $\mathcal{L},\mathcal{L}'$ with $\mathcal{L}\otimes\mathcal{L}'^{-1}$, suffices to show that if $\mathcal{L}$ restricted to the $n$th thickening of the closed point of $R$ is trivial for all $n$, then $\mathcal{L}$ is trivial. By formal function theorem, we see that the completion of $f_*\mathcal{L}$ is the completion of $R$ and then it is standard to show that $f_*\mathcal{L}$ is $R$ and the the map $R\to f_*\mathcal{L}\otimes R/m^n$ is a surjection for all $n$. So, this section will give a trivialization of $\mathcal{L}$.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I didn't notice that you don't have that assumption...

Comment: @Mohan I am a bit slow here. I do not understand which section gives the trivialization of $\mathcal{L}$, in particular, I do not see any morphism from $\mathcal{L}$ to $\mathcal{O}_X$. Could please give me one more hint on this.

Comment: $f_*\mathcal{L}$ are sections of $\mathcal{L}$ and thus the element $1\in R=f_*\mathcal{L}$ gives a section $\mathcal{O}_X\to\mathcal{L}$ which one shows is an isomorphism.

Comment: @Mohan Thanks a lot. I think I understand now.